# Difference between CPU usage in top and /proc/stat

Tags: cpu, proc, top, cpu-usage

I'm trying to write a little script that, among other things, calculates the cpu usage by reading `/proc/stat`, and I can't seem to get consistent results. I'm basically doing a

```
grep cpu /proc/stat
```

and then processing the first line that is supposed to accumulate data from all the threads. In my case I've got 4 cores/8 threads. I've also written a program that constantly occupies one thread just to test stuff (it's basically a `while(1) { 1 }`). In this context if I'm doing nothing else I would expect 12.5% cpu usage, and if I run `top`, I get that:

```
%Cpu(s): 12,7 usuario,  0,1 sist,  0,0 adecuado, 87,1 inact,  0,1 en espera,  0,
```

(sorry that it's in another language). The first line of `/proc/stat`, though, is as follows:

```
cpu  1490042 169968 416799 32056116 21179 0 19504 0 0 0
```

And if I calculate the percentage from here:

```
(1490042 + 169968 + 416799)/(1490042 + 169968 + 416799 + 32056116) = 6%
```

Why the inconsistency? I guess I'm not interpreting `/proc/stat` properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to answer my question since finding an answer wasn't all that hard, I just misread the documentation on `/proc/stat`

`/proc/stat` shows aggregated data since bootup, therefore to calculate average cpu usage during a given time interval, you have to calculate the differences of the values given in `/proc/stat` at the beginning and end of that time interval.

Comment: This was good reading as well. https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65143